# Workaround for missing .TypeName of SqlParameter in plain .NET 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-2.0, sqlclient

In plain .NET2 Framework (no service packs) there is no property

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.TypeName
```

My app is built on a machine with .NET2 SP1 installed. It is executed in hundreds of other machines and some of them do not have .NET2 SP1, and probably they won't install them so they get this exception:

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_TypeName(System.String)'
```

From the c# code I execute SQL scripts (NO stored procedure calls, just sql scripts) that use DataTable objects as inputs, and this means you have to define the table-valued parameter's name from c# code (When executing stored procedures, this name is defined on the procedure's declaration, and you don't have to define it again). Apparently, I can't do this when .NET2 SP1 is not installed.

My question is:

**Is there a way to define the Table-valued parameter's name from C# code using plain .NET2 framework (No SP1 installed)??
How can I execute simple sql scripts that use table-valued inputs from c# code, without having the SP1 of .NET2?**

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589246/2375071

Comment: @RanjanKumar thanx for commenting, event though it was an old question. Today this question is irrelevant to me, since microsoft stopped supporting windows XP, our company officially stopped supporting .net2-.net4. We now force our clients to upgrade to at least Win7 and .net452